# react native image source from uri or require

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating an app with native react and I'll like to use an already loaded image if there is no image uploaded from user... so how do I dynamically choose uri or require?

Which is the correct syntax?

here is my code :

```
var profileImage = "require('../../assets/images/blue.png')";
var profileImageUri = "{uri:'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/43.jpg'}";

return(
      <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.userImage}>
              <Avatar
                rounded
                size={150}
                title={!this.state.profile_picture ? this.state.firstLetter : ''}
                source={
                    this.state.profile_picture ? profileImage : profileImageUri
                }
              />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

which do not triggers any error but DO NOT work.

Thanks

Comment: you can  import image e.g `import profileImage from 'path/of/image.extension'` and use as source, here extension would be your image file  format e.g  jpg/png

Answer (score 3):

Remove the double quotes. It shouldn't be a string.

```
var profileImage = require('../../assets/images/blue.png');
var profileImageUri = {uri:'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/43.jpg'};
```